# Best way to shrink service class to smaller pieces

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently making a large app with Flutter and I m stuck on the architecture of service class. There is a service class for the firestore CRUD operations.This class has many methods and I want split it into small pieces. I use an abstract class to protect methods.I find a way with mixins but don't know it's a good one or not.

https://gist.github.com/pMertDogan/fcd301d768f3980a898cec33a9acaa4f.

```
//Extend CRUDSERVICE rules aka abstract class => Test
mixin Update{
  
  void updateSomething();
  
}

mixin Read{
  void readSomething();
}

//BASE class for CRUDSERVICE 
abstract class Test with Update,Read{
  doSomeCreateOP(String x);
}

//
class CrudService extends Test with UpdateService , ReadService{
  @override
  doSomeCreateOP(String x) {
    print('crated ' + x);
  }
    
      
      
    }
    
    mixin UpdateService{
    //   @override
      void updateSomething() {
       print('updated');
      }
    }
    
    mixin ReadService{
    //   @override
      void readSomething() {
       print('read');
      }
    }
    
    
    void main() {
      CrudService croudService = CrudService();
      croudService.doSomeCreateOP(' dartSide');
      croudService.updateSomething();
      croudService.readSomething();
    }
```

CreateService and UpdateService mixins are just sample.I am thinking like if I need update user information all methods are handed by UserServiceMix mixin if it's Friend then its hanled by FriendServiceMix so  I can split them like a domain-based.Each mixin is responsible for specific operations.I can manage then on independent files and summary of them with the help of mixin.

Is it good way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a good way to go. It is a quite flexible approach. We use it for API versioning as well.

```dart
abstract class Service {
  void method1();
  void method2();
}

mixin Method1V1 {
  void method1() {
    print("method1");
  }
}

mixin Method2V1 {
  void method2() {
    print("method2");
  }
}

mixin Method2V2 {
  void method2() {
    print("method2 with changed logic");
  }
}

class ServiceV1 extends Service with Method1V1, Method2V1 {

}

class ServiceV2 extends Service with Method1V1, Method2V2 {

}

void main() {
  final version = 2;

  final Service service = version == 1 ? ServiceV1() : ServiceV2();

  service.method2();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene! I was pointed my question related dividing dataProvider to small pieces. https://gist.github.com/pMertDogan/59eea706ef6fec3894fce2be7913067d